# Having communication between android mobile and laptop?

Tags: android, communication, android-wifi

My project is based on a client-server architecture where laptop is my server and my Android smartphone (Samsung Galaxy) is my client.

So, what I want to know is: "How do I create communication channel between these two devices using WiFi or any other method?"

Answer (score 1):

The first way that comes to my mind would be to do so by using [Socket Communication](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html).

If you don't know your way around Socket communication, I'd suggest you do a little bit of research prior to starting your project.

First just create a dummy server and dummy client on your PC and have them communicate, at this point the information transmitted doesn't really matter, simple Strings would be just fine.

After you've accomplished that, transfer the code from the PC Client to your phone, that should be pretty easy to do as they should work just the same.

"Google-ing" for Beginner Socket Tutorials should get you started in no time.

Hope this helps, and if you run into any problems later on, I'm sure the community will be very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

you should first develop and test project on android emulator.For simple communication you can use httppost or httpget.